# Request NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription permission

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios11

I'm trying to save image to Photos app on iOS 10 and 11 versions. [Therefore](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW73) on iOS 11 I need to request `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` permission, on iOS 10 `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`.

As Apple documentation [claims](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phphotolibrary/1620736-requestauthorization?language=objc), `[PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:]` obtains permission **only** for `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key.

If you have both keys in `Info.plist` file and select "Add photos only" to Photos permissions in your app, `[PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus]` returns `PHAuthorizationStatusDenied`.

Does anybody know how to deal with these permissions?

Comment: I added both to my Info.plist and each key's name was changed. The iOS 10 one became "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" and the iOS 11 one became "Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description". I didn't use "[PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus]" -- I only clicked OK when the Privacy question came up in a dialog box when I was storing a screenshot of the app in Photos as part of the function of the app. And it worked just fine.

Comment: Ted this drives my team crazy. Did you find a solution for this? It drives us crazy

Comment: @RoiMulia As I remember (I don't have access to that code anymore), I tried to access both read and write permissions and stated that this is only for write. And it worked on iOS 10 as well as on iOS 11. Also, App Store approved this. But I don't know if it works now.

Comment: Thank for responding, The issue is that I'm accessing it via UIActivityController so it's only triggering save option..