# What is the crash of "The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription"?

Tags: ios, permissions, ios11

I faced the following error (iOS 11):

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain
>   an `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` key with a string value
>   explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Note that although the application *info.plist* does contains `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` it still crashes, why?

Comment: why are you are asking question then if you know the answer ?

Comment: @VarunNaharia because I think it might be useful for anyone facing this crash. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d it is legal :)

Comment: There are already same question there you can answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566972/request-nsphotolibraryaddusagedescription-permission
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344159/whats-difference-between-nsphotolibraryaddusagedescription-and-nsphotolibraryus

Comment: @VarunNaharia If I'm not mistaking, these options (as mentioned inhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341694/detect-add-photos-only-permission question) are unavailable for now... or at least I couldn't find them :)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

> Note that although the application info.plist does contains
>   `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` it still crashes, why?

I think there is a misunderstanding when comparing `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription`, as documented in [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW74):

NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription:

> This key lets you describe the reason your app **accesses** the user’s
>   photo library. When the system prompts the user to allow access, this
>   string is displayed as part of the alert.

It is related to letting the app to be able to **access** (get) the device photos library.

NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription:

> This key lets you describe the reason your app seeks **write-only access**
>   to the user’s photo library. When the system prompts the user to allow
>   access, this string is displayed as part of the alert.

It is related to letting the app to be able to **write** (add) photos into the device photos library.

Obviously, to solve this crash you have to add the `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` into the application's plist file:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Our application needs permission to write photos...</string>
```

As property list view:

[image]

Comment: Apple’s documentation for `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` specifically states that it is for both read & write access: "Although this keys governs **read and write access** to the user’s photo library, it’s best to use NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription if your app needs only to add assets to the library and does not need to read any assets.” I don’t know if this is just a bug in the Documentation or if Apple purposefully changed the behavior for `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` to be read-only.

Comment: @Cutterpillow I think your second assumption it correct.

Comment: If you open iOS settings and navigation to your app you will see *read and write* with *NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription*. That is why it looks like a bug

Comment: If you want to add photos to the library you need to use the "Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description" key. I used both that key and the "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" keys and things worked properly.

Comment: Hi, still the same issue after a few years. My question is, how I can ask for permission for "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription"? Or I just need to add Key, String to my plist file?  @AhmadF

Comment: @A.Amini you have to add it into the plist.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in the above answer. The correct plist entry should be as follows

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs permission to access photos on your device</string>
```